# How to get correct connection info for redis cartridge?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I installed the redis cartridge from here: https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart

Installation is fine and redis works perfectly.
However, when I run:

`rhc cartridge-status redis -a <yourapp>`

I get this: 
Using smarterclayton-redis-2.6 (Redis) for 'redis'

RESULT:

```
Redis is running
  slave
  Connect to: [url to application].rhcloud.com: password: [correct redis password]
Redis Sentinel is not running
```

According the the github page, that should instead give me the url to the redis instance with the port.  Also, the info about the instance being a slave is wrong ?

Does anybody know how I could get the correct connection info ?

Comment: having the same issue. did you figure this out?

Comment: @aschmid00: unfortunately not ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two things.
1.)  SSH into your application and use the env command to look at your environment variables and see if you have any for the redis connection, maybe something like env | grep redis
2.)  Log an issue against the github repo where you found the redis cartridge, and I am sure that clayton will get it sorted out.

Comment: If you plan to connect directly to redis console I'd recommend using `rhc port-forward` and then locally connect to given ports. Inside your application you should always use environment variables as this give you 100% sure to be always accurate. In this case you're interested in `OPENSHIFT_REDIS_HOST`, `OPENSHIFT_REDIS_PORT` and `REDIS_PASSWORD`.